# Click item in grid and some action should happen

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to make ability to edit items(cells) by clicking them in Grid.
I want to have possibility to click ex. ITEM1 and some action should takes place.
I know that I can use renderer, but it returns only string.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in ExtJS Cell Editing Grid?

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.html

Or you can edit the entire row at once:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/row-editing.html